# MeasurementFormatter not working as intended

Tags: swift, measurementformatter

```
let userDefined = Measurement(value: Double(userInput.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)

let calculatedValue = userDefined.converted(to: UnitMass.grams)

print(calculatedValue)

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
Convertedunit.text = formatter.string(from: calculatedValue)
```

The user input is `5`.

The output of `print(calculatedValue)` is `5000.0g`.

However, the output of `Convertedunit.text` is `11.003lbs` which is in pounds. I tried to use different methods, but it is still not in grams. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Because of `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")`, the formatter will automatically convert everything to the imperial unit system, which in this case is pounds. Grams on the other hand belong to the metric system.

**There are two ways to change this behaviour:**

**A)** If you want to use the metric system specify a locale for a country that uses it, such as Germany. `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")`. Don't worry, this will not affect the language of the string ( such as German: Meter, English: Meters, French: Mètres) as that is still bound to the apps language.

**B)** If you want to keep whatever unit you put into the formatter simply declare: `formatter.unitOptions = .init(arrayLiteral: .providedUnit)`
That way the formatter will generate strings with whatever unit you have provided it with.